# How to properly host my ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net

I'm not very experienced with ASP.NET, I've started to learn about all of this a month or so ago, I've made a very simple website that I would like to test online, there are no database connections or anything of the sorts.

My previous experience with the Web has taught me to just upload files via an FTP client and being done, this is obviously not the case with ASP.NET.

I'm running Visual Web Developer Express and having a really hard time understanding how to get my website online on my host. I've read a few things about the web.config file, I've changed my server to support version 4.0, but I still battle with error after error after uploading my files onto my server. I've also read that the Express edition is limited in the "Publish Website" department.

I'd just like a direct answer on how to publish my website onto my host.

Comment: Your web host needs to be running Windows or Apache+Mono for this to work.

Comment: Yes, I have access to a web host that runs on windows. That's where I placed all the files, but first I get a Web.Config error about custom errors, fixing that brings in another error, and another... list goes on forever, I can't be doing this right.

Comment: what errors you are getting now ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your hosting company supports ASP.NET websites. Get a FTP client like FileZilla. Copy all of your files to the remote directory. If you are using a database, change the connection string in your web.config file to match the connection string of your new database. You get the connection string from the hosting company.

Comment: And this is it?... I mean, this is where I'm at: http://www.trilogianocturnus.com/jdlferreira/

That's the first error I got. After including this <customErrors mode="Off"/> line on my Web.config file, I get more errors... errors that I don't have locally, it's all working fine locally really.

My host uses Parallels Plesk, I've tried changing my ASP.NET version there form 2.0 to 4.0 (I've read this suggestion on the web), but it seems that after changing it, it resets back to 2.0, is this part of my problems or?..

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to deploy your Asp.net web site.

1. Web Setup Project: Create a web setup project and use the resulting files to deploy your application. [Read More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kzx145%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. Copy Web Site Tool: Update and deploy websites in environments with multiple developers and servers. [Read More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay0wxbf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
3. Publish website tool: Pre compile your websites.
   [Read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx)

Comment: I've tried using the Copy Website Tool, made a copy of my project, uploaded those files, same result.

Comment: what problem u are facing ? I'm unable to understand your problem. Plz clear me

Comment: trilogianocturnus.com/jdlferreira , First I get that web.config file error, so i fix it by putting that <customErrors mode="Off"/> line in. After that I just keep getting error after error on my pages, stuff like master page can't be found...

Comment: okay. Do you try precompile website method ? it is easy. One other method is to put all of your files on the web server. For this you have to create directories on the webserver as it was created in Visual Express Studio. You get the master page error, Possible reason may be that you have placed the master page at the wrong location. If you have created a directory in your Local Machine like      a folder with name MasterPages then it should also be created on Web Server.

Comment: I don't have any Publish Website option under Build in Visual Web Developer Express, do I need a full version for that?

Also, the master age is in the right place, I put the whole folder into the host server, there is no way it's going into different folders and whatnot.

Comment: yes. It is not available in express edition. Do you try Copy Web Site tool ? it allows publish website to remote PC's using FTP.

Comment: Yes, I synchronized all the files into a new folder I created, I then uploaded all those files into my web host, still getting the same errors. I have no FTP option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13581/discussion-between-waqar-janjua-and-joao-ferreira)